# How to grant full permission to a folder to all users of a windows machine using java program?

Tags: java

My java program need to grant Full access to a Folder for all users of the Windows desktop system where my program runs.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Windows\\System32\" && icacls "+"\""+modifiedJavapath+"\""+ " /grant \"Users\":F ");

        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            builder.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
File file = new File("mioFile.txt");

 file.setExecutable(boolean); – true, allow execute operations; false to disallow it.
 file.setReadable(boolean); – true, allow read operations; false to disallow it.
 file.setWritable(boolean); – true, allow write operations; false to disallow it.

 file.canExecute(); – return true, file is executable; false is not.
 file.canWrite(); – return true, file is writable; false is not.
 file.canRead(); – return true, file is readable; false is not.
```